# Typeerror: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Decimal' and 'float'

Tags: python, floating-point

Here is my code: I have tried all day to solve the mistake but I still have the error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Decimal' and 'float'.

```
from math import sqrt, acos, pi

from decimal import Decimal, getcontext

getcontext().prec = 30

class Vector(object):

    CANNOT_NORMALIZE_ZERO_VECTOR_MSG = 'Cannot compute an angle with the zero vector'

    def __init__(self, coordinates):
        try:
            if not coordinates:
                raise ValueError
            self.coordinates = tuple(Decimal(x) for x in coordinates)
            self.dimension = len(self.coordinates)

        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError('The coordinates must be nonempty')

        except TypeError:
            raise TypeError('The coordinates must be an iterable')
    #orthogonal or parallel
    def is_zero(self, tolerance=1e-10):
        return self.magnitude() < tolerance

    def is_orthogonal_to(self, v, tolerance=1e-10):
        return abs(self.dot(v)) < tolerance

    def is_parallel_to(self, v):
        return ( self.is_zero() or 
                v.is_zero() or
                self.angle_with(v) == 0 or
                self.angle_with(v) == pi )

    #dot product &angle
    def dot(self, v):
        return sum([x*y for x,y in zip(self.coordinates,v.coordinates)])
    def angle_with(self,v,in_degrees=False):
        try:
            u1 = self.normalized()
            u2 = v.normalized()
            angle_in_radians = acos(u1.dot(u2))

            if in_degrees:
                degrees_per_radian = 180./pi
                return angle_in_radians * degrees_per_radian
            else:
                return angle_in_radians

        except Exception as e:
            if str(e) == self.CANNOT_NORMALIZE_ZERO_VECTOR_MSG:
                raise Exception('Cannot compute an angle with the zero vector')
            else:
                raise e


    #magnitude& Direction
    def magnitude(self):
        coordinates_squared = [x**2 for x in self.coordinates]
        return sqrt(sum(coordinates_squared))
    def normalized(self):
        try:
            magnitude = self.magnitude()
            return self.times_scalar(Decimal('1.0')/magnitude)
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            raise Exception(self.CANNOT_NORMALIZE_ZERO_VECTOR_MSG)
    #Plus,minus, scalar multiply
    def plus(self, v):
        new_coordinates = [x+y for x,y in zip(self.coordinates,v.coordinates)]
        return Vector(new_coordinates)
    def minus(self, v):
        new_coordinates = [x-y for x,y in zip(self.coordinates,v.coordinates)]
        return Vector(new_coordinates)
    def times_scalar(self, c):
        new_coordinates = [Decimal(c)*x for x in self.coordinates]
        return Vector(new_coordinates)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Vector: {}'.format(self.coordinates)

    def __eq__(self, v):
        return self.coordinates == v.coordinates

v = Vector(['8','-9'])

w = Vector(['-1','-1'])

print v.dot(w)

print v.angle_with(w)

print v.angle_with(w, in_degrees=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

In general it usually does not make sense to mix `Decimal` and `float` math.  Not sure why you need `Decimal` here, but with two small changes this code can be made to run.  I would suggest considering getting rid of the `Decimal` unless you are sure you need it:

Change magnitude to:

```
# magnitude& Direction
def magnitude(self):
    coordinates_squared = [x ** 2 for x in self.coordinates]
    return sum(coordinates_squared) ** Decimal('0.5')
```

And the `acos` call to:

```
angle_in_radians = Decimal(str(acos(u1.dot(u2))))
```